# Dynamically Calculating field value with js and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So ive been trying to calculate automatically exchange rates with a rate i get from php and send it to a js script. Unfortunates the first field is calculated correctly but the second stops at a limit. ive tried this approach

```
  <fieldset>

                        

            
                                        <div class="col-12" style="margin-left: -1rem !important;">
                                            <h6 class="py-50" for="paypal">Choose What You Sell</h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row mb-75">
                                            <div class="col-12 d-flex">
                                                <div class="cursor-pointer d-flex align-items-center">
                                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                                        <img src="../app-assets/images/pages/btc.png" alt="BTC Logo">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="option" onchange="hideB(this)" id="btc" value="BTC" checked>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="cursor-pointer pl-1 d-flex align-items-center">
                                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                                        <img src="../app-assets/images/pages/eth.png" height="30" alt="ETH Logo">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="option" onchange="hideA(this)" id="eth" value="ETH">
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                       
                                        <div class="row" id="A">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="value_n">Enter Your amount in USD </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="value_btc" name="value_btc" class="form-control required" onkeyup="mult(this.value);" data-validation-regex-regex="([^a-z]*[A-Z]*)*" data-validation-containsnumber-regex="([^0-9]*[0-9]+)+" min="50" max="100000" data-validation-containsnumber-message="Min. $50 Max. $100,000" required placeholder="Enter Number of Your Value">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount in BTC</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="btc_rate" name="btc_rate" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in BTC" >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount You will Receive (BTC - ₦ NAIRA)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receive_btc" name="receive_btc" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in Naira" >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" id="B" style="display:none">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="firstName13">Enter Your amount in USD </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="value_eth" name="value_eth" class="form-control required" onkeyup="mult2(this.value);" data-validation-regex-regex="([^a-z]*[A-Z]*)*" data-validation-containsnumber-regex="([^0-9]*[0-9]+)+" min="50" max="100000" data-validation-containsnumber-message="Min. $50 Max. $100,000" required placeholder="Enter Number of Your Value">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount in ETH</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eth_rate" name="eth_rate" name="eth_rate" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in BTC" >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount You will Receive (ETH - ₦ NAIRA)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receive_eth" name="receive_eth" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in BTC" >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

im using the js below to calculate the field value for btc and how much the client will recieve:

```
        <script>
        function mult(value_btc) {
            var btc_rate = "<?php echo $btc_rate; ?>";
         <!-- END: Theme JS-->
         var x, y ;
            x = value_btc / btc_rate ;
            y = btc_rate * 4 ;

            document.getElementById('btc_rate').value = x;
            document.getElementById('receive_btc').value = y;
        }

    </script>

<script>
        function mult2(value_eth) {
         var eth_rate = "<?php echo $eth_rate; ?>";

         var x, y ;
            x = value_eth / eth_rate ;
            y = eth_rate * 4 ;

            document.getElementById('eth_rate').value = x;
            document.getElementById('receive_eth').value = y;
        }
</script>
```

the x values work correctly but the y value stops at a limit.
will really appreciate if someone can help out. thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate more.

Comment: basically i will like to type a value on the first field and js calculates the values on the other fields

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Comment: What do you mean " _y value stops at a limit_  "?